# How would you design the abstraction/class(es)/component(s) of a third-party service/api used in your application?

Tags: design, object-oriented, python, authentication

Lets say you were designing a Twitter client for people with people could see tweets and post tweets? How would you design the twitter api abstraction? Many of the api wrappers I've seen feature an client object that takes as input, the credentials of a user. Something similar to the code below:

```
twitter = TwitterClient(auth) # maybe (username & password) OR token
twitter.post_tweet(message)
```

To me, this client is now bound to this user and only operate on this user's account. If another user logs in, should we create another client object or is there a better way? It seems like the program memory would dramatically increase if every user initiated the instantiation of a program object? Is there a better way to this?

Comment: `It seems like the program memory would dramatically increase`. Don't guess, do test and get some metrics first. Making decisions based on guesswork only leads to mediocre results.

Answer (score 0):

Having the client bound to a user or connection string or whatever can be a good thing. But yes there are occasions where you need to have a different user each time you call a method on the client.

A simplistic approach might be

```
twitter.AnyMethod(parameters, auth)
```

But isn't very neat to have to have this extra parameter on all methods.

You could have an extra Login/Init method or a Auth parameter

```
twitter = new TwitterClient();
twitter.Login(auth);
//twitter.Auth = auth;
twitter.AnyMethod(params);
```

But its not very thread safe, especially if you are passing the twitter client around.

Another approach is to inject a function which will return the auth and have this function be context dependent.

```
twitter = new TwitterClient(() => {return HttpContext.User.TwitterAuthCode; })
twitter.AnyMethod(params);
```

This is nice as you can fall back easily to simply passing in a single auth and you don't have to change the methods

You can get more complex and maybe override a hashmap or dictionary, so that the key is used to pass in the auth

```
twitter = new TwitterClient();
twitter[auth].AnyMethod(params);
```

Not so great for auth perhaps, but nice if you have a list of possible things that's not known until the client is able to contact the server.

Answer (score 0):

It's completely fine to have one `TwitterClient` per user.

> It seems like the program memory would dramatically increase if every user initiated the instantiation of a program object?

Why, what instance data does the client object actually have? I believe it would only have the user's authentication data; the rest of it is just methods. If for whatever reason you have a lot of stuff in the client object, you could create a separate `User` class or something, and that would store the authentication data and then use the client:

```
client = TwitterClient()
user = TwitterUser(client, auth)
user.post_message(...)
```

But that shouldn't be necessary in most cases.